# Codeigniter 1.7.2 support for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I'm starting a new project that requires me to rewrite an existing PHP application using  Codeigniter framework (v1.7.2).  The existing application's database is in SQL Server 2008.  The application has a lot of stored procedures that I'm required to incorporate.

Does anybody have experience using Codeigniter with SQL Server?  Was the experience successful?  Should I used the mssql driver or the ODBC driver?

I found an older codeigniter forum here but the information is a bit dated.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/91918/P15/

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Doctrine ORM**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) 1.2 or 2 (its still in beta).

Maybe this can help you :

[using doctrine 2 with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263411)

or this

[Doctrine 1.2 + MS SQL Server 2008](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/30293ca21dfe8939?tvc=2)

Comment: Thanks.  I will definitely look at Doctrine if CI database driver doesn't hold up with SQL Server.